# Finitely generated torsion-free modules over Dedekind domain

Tags: commutative-algebra, algebraic-number-theory

Let $A$ be a Dedekind domain and $L$ be a finitely generated torsion-free $A$-module of rank $d$. Let $a\in A$ be a non-zero element. I want to prove $L/aL\cong (A/aA)^d$.

Here's the idea. By the structure theorem of finitely generated torsion-free module over a Dedekind domain, we have $L\cong A^{d-1}\oplus I$ for a non-zero ideal $I$ in $A$. Then, $$L/aL\cong (A/aA)^{d-1}\oplus I/aI.$$ It suffices to prove $I/aI\cong A/aA$. I know $I/aI\cong I\otimes_A A/aA$ and $I$ is an invertible ideal. Can this imply that $I/aI\cong A/aA$?

Comment: Hint: There are only finitely many maximal ideals containing $a$.

Comment: I was trying to factorize $(a) =\prod_{i=1}^r \mathfrak{p}_i^{e_i}$ and then use Chinese Remainder theorem (for modules). Is that what you mean? I feel that I can prove $A/\mathfrak{p}\cong I/\mathfrak{p}I$.

Comment: $I$ and $aI$ become principal in $A/bA$ for $b\in aI-0$